# Todo List App in React Error: no-unused-expressions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

So I am trying to make a To-Do-List App in ReactJS but I got an error:

> /src/todoList.js   Line 40:21:  Expected an assignment or function
> call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions.

I am storing all the tasks in the state of Todolist and using a `.map()` which returns another component called TodoItem. I am pretty new to the react environment and have been not able to figure out the error myself.

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoItem from './components/todoItem';

class TodoList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            todos: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    title: 'Take out the trash',
                    completed: false
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'Clean the room',
                    completed: false
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    title: 'Wash the dishes',
                    completed: false
                },
            ]
        }
    }

    render() {
       const todos = this.state.todos;
      
       
            return (
               
                   todos.map((todo) => {
                    //console.log(todo);
                    <TodoItem todo = {todo} />
                    })
               
                
            )
    
       
    }
}

export default TodoList;
```

The **TodoItem** Component.
It is a separate component for each item of the Todo list.

```
import React from 'react';

class TodoItem extends React.Component {
    
    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <h3>{this.props.todo.title}</h3>
        )
    }
}

export default TodoItem;
```

Comment: You are not actually returning `TodoItem` inside the map ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
return (
               
                   todos.map((todo) => {
                    //console.log(todo);
                    <TodoItem todo = {todo} />
                    })
```

Should be:

```
return (<>{todos.map((todo) => <TodoItem todo = {todo} />)}</>)
```

Answer (score 0):

- you do well just a tiny mistake happened in the `map` method you didn't return any thing so it gave you a warning that there is nothing to render so the solution is this:

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoItem from './components/todoItem';

class TodoList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            todos: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    title: 'Take out the trash',
                    completed: false
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    title: 'Clean the room',
                    completed: false
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    title: 'Wash the dishes',
                    completed: false
                },
            ]
        }
    }

    render() {
       const todos = this.state.todos;
      
       
            return (
               
                   todos.map((todo) => {
                    //console.log(todo);
                    return <TodoItem todo = {todo} />
                    })
               
                
            )
    
       
    }
}

export default TodoList;
```

Comment: all those items need to be enclosed by an element though

Answer (score 0):

You should use () instead of {} in the map function like this:

```
 return (               
      todos.map((todo) => (            
          <TodoItem todo = {todo} />
      ))             
            
  )
```

Or add return statement if you want to use curly brackets like this:

```
return (               
      todos.map((todo) => {            
          return <TodoItem todo = {todo} />
      })             
            
  )
```